# Non-zero exit code (1) error for pip install numpy

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to install Numpy on Pycharm and I keep getting errors. Is there something I could do in the command prompt to fix this? using python 3.7

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the whole error?

Comment: Think that should be it

Comment: @RossLamon That only shows part of the error. Can you copy-paste the text into your post?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED :)

Had to add
C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3;C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3\Library\bin;

to my path